# sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: "None"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am developing the Web Application in Flask built on top of Docker images. One image stores the Postgres Database. I am struggling with inserting `None` into the Integer column defined followingly:

```py
release = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=True)
```

Row initialization:

```py
    def __init__(self, name: str, env: str, mode: ExecutionMode, status: ExecutionStatus, date: datetime, user_id: int,
                 release_id: int):
        self.execution_name = name
        self.environment = env
        self.execution_mode = mode
        self.execution_status = status
        self.execution_date = date
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.release = release_id

        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
```

Caller's method:

```py
    if request.method == "POST":
        execution = Execution(name=data['result']['name'], env=Environment[data['result']['env']],
                              mode=ExecutionMode[data['result']['mode']],
                              status=ExecutionStatus[data['result']['status']],
                              date=datetime.datetime.strptime(data['result']['date'], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"),
                              user_id=current_user.id,
                              release_id=(data['result']['release'] if data['result'][
                                                                           'release'] != "null" else sqlalchemy.null()))
```

Whenever I encounter the case, that the value of the Release is `None`, the following exception is triggered:

```py
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation) invalid input syntax for type integer: "None"
```

Does anyone know, how to insert the `None` respectively `NULL` value into the database?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is it `None` the object or a string `"None"`? The error hints at the latter.

Comment: Hello, I clarified the issue's description. To answer your question it is `None` object, however it seems that SQLAlchemy natively converts it into the `str`, hence `"None"`.

Comment: @michal.kyjovsky Are you sure?  I can reproduce the error message with `str(None)` but not with the object `None`.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The problem is actually on the front-end in the form that accepts the data. There supposed to be the value of "null" in the select box, however "None" was select. I missed that. Seems, that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is actually on the front-end in the form that accepts the data. There was supposed to be the value of "null" in the select box; however, "None" was the value of the select. I missed that. It seems that the issue is solved.